# "function" object not subscriptable when using os.getenv

Tags: python-3.x, function

Me again with another (probably) dumb question.

I'm currently working on a piece of coursework and was asked to do a piece on sending an sms via Twilio when a condition is met.

The idea is when the condition is met it sends an sms:

(only showing relevant snippets of code as i've narrowed it down to this part causing the
issue)

```
from notification_manager import NotificationManager

nm = NotificationManager()

    if flight.price <= destination["lowestPrice"]:
        nm.send_sms(
            message = f"LOW PRICE ALERT! ONLY €{flight.price} to fly from {flight.origin_city}-{flight.origin_airport} to {flight.destination_city}-{flight.destination_airport}, from {flight.out_date} to {flight.return_date}." 
        )
```

ON THE NotificationManager class is where i get the issue however, when i hit run it tells me this error:

```
  File "c:\Users\Speakr\Desktop\Py101\Day31-40\Day39&40 - Flight club & deal finder\flight-deals-start\notification_manager.py", line 11, in <module>
    SID = os.getenv["TWILIO_SID"]
TypeError: 'function' object is not subscriptable
```

This is my code for the notification manager:

```
#----IMPORTS----#

import os
from dotenv import load_dotenv
from twilio.rest import Client

#----CONSTANTS & FUNCTIONS----#

load_dotenv()

SID = os.getenv["TWILIO_SID"]
AUTH_TOKEN = os.getenv["TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN"]
VIRTUAL_NUMBER = os.getenv["TWILIO_VIRTUAL_NUMBER"]
VERIFIED_NUMBER = os.getenv["TWILIO_VERIFIED_NUMBER"]

class NotificationManager:
    #This class will be used to send the SMS when the conditions are met. 
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        #This is us logging into the client with our credentials
        self.client = Client(SID, AUTH_TOKEN)

    def send_SMS(self, message):
        #This method will send the message, the message will be created with our client credentials
        #as stated above, the message itself is defined in main.py and passed here as an argument
        #and then the message is sent from our TWILIO_VIRTUAL to our REAL number
        message = self.client.messages.create(
            body = message,
            from_=VIRTUAL_NUMBER,
            to=VERIFIED_NUMBER,
        )
        #Error handling, will print if successfully sent
        print(message.sid)
```

At first I thought ok, must be that the Constants were using the same name as the os.getenv[""] parts. As that is where the error is pointing to. But even after changing them ex:

```
Twilio_SID = os.getenv["Twilio_SID"] is now just SID = os.getenv["Twilio_SID"]
```

I still run into the error. Any fresh eyes want to help me out here. I'm actually stumped.

Comment: `os.getenv` is a function and should be called like `os.getenv("Twilio_SID")`. You are subscripting it with `os.getenv["Twilio_SID"]`. (Think indexing into a `list` or accessing a key from a `dict`)

Answer (score 0):

**TLDR**:

Change your

```
os.getenv["variable_name"]
```

to use round brackets instead.

```
os.getenv("variable_name")
```

---

Credit goes to @Axe319 for their comment:

> `os.getenv` is a function and should be called like `os.getenv("Twilio_SID")`. You are subscripting it with `os.getenv["Twilio_SID"]`. (Think indexing into a list or accessing a key from a dict)

I just tested this locally and it fixed the issue for me.